# Proving the asymptotic of $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x^{a+1}}\,dx$ for $a \to 0^+$ is $\pi/2$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, improper-integrals

I am working on finding the asymptotic of $\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos x}{x^a} \, dx$ for $a\to0^+$. And I have reduced the problem on finding the asymptotic of $a\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x^{a+1}} \,d x$. The result is known to be $a\pi/2$ if $a\to0^+$ and there is my proof.
$$a\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x^{a+1}} \,dx = a\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin x}{x^{a+1}} \, dx + a\int_{\pi/2}^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x^{a+1}} \, dx$$
On the other hand $a\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin x}{x^{a+1}}\,dx$ behaves as $a\pi/2$ and $a\int_{\pi/2}^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x^{a+1}} \, dx  = O(1)$.
However the problem is that $a\pi/2$ is way smaller that $1$. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you integrate by parts once more. (Note that $(1 - \cos x)' = \sin x$.)

Comment: It is known that $$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\cos t}}{{t^a }}dt}  = \Gamma (1 - a)\sin \left( {\frac{\pi }{2}a} \right)$$ for $0 < \Re a < 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I tried, but I don't get $a\pi/2$ (I don't get $\pi$ at all).

Comment: @Gary Yes, that is lovely, but I'm afraid I can't use Gamma functions. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Well, what do you get when you integrate by parts again?

Comment: I got the asymptotic $\frac{4a}{1-a}$ using that $\sin x < x$ for $0<x<1$ and $\sin x \leq 1$ everywhere else. Btw, can I simply assume that, knowing $\int_0^\infty \sin x/x = \pi/2$ and for $a\to 0$ our integral acts like $\int_0^\infty \sin x/x$, our asymptotic is $\pi/2$?

Comment: It's not quite so simple, to interchange the order of taking a limit and integration needs a justification. That justification is usually easier when you deal with absolutely convergent integrals. You get one when you integrate by parts again, which is why I suggested that. One can also justify it without integrating by parts, by splitting the integral at a large $R$ (and considering the limit as $R \to \infty$).

Comment: Integrating by parts once more should, for $0 < a < 1$, yield $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x^{a+1}}\,dx = \frac{1-\cos x}{x^{a+1}}\biggr\rvert_0^{\infty} + (a+1)\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos x}{x^{a+2}}\,dx = (a+1)\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos x}{x^{a+2}}\,dx\,.$$ In that, taking the limit $a \to 0$ is rather easy to justify. The limit is of course $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\,dx = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2 y}{y^2}\,dy = \frac{\pi}{2}\,.$$

Comment: You have already had an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3697492/finding-the-asymptotic-of-an-integral/3697768

Comment: This question is interesting in a number of ways: $$
\begin{align} & \int_{1\,\longleftarrow\,\text{“1'', not “0''}}^\infty \left| \frac{\sin x}{x^{a+1}} \right|\,dx <+\infty \text{ when } a>0 \\ {} \\ & \int_0^1 \left| \frac{\sin x}{x^{a+1}} \right| \, dx <+\infty \text{ when } 0<a<1 \\ {} \\
\text{but } & \int_0^1 \left| \frac{\sin x} x \right| \, dx = +\infty \\ {} \\
\text{but } & \lim_{m\,\to\,\infty} \int_0^m \frac{\sin x} x \,dx \text{ exists and is finite,}
\end{align}
$$
and that last limit is equal to $$\lim_{a\,\downarrow\, 0} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x} {x^{a+1}} \, dx.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $0<a<1$. Since $x^{a}\sin x\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow0}0$, integration by parts gives

$$
\int^M_0x^{-a}\cos x\,dx = M^{-a}\sin M +a\int ^M_0x^{-a-1}\sin x\,dx
$$

Sine $x^{-a-1}(1-\cos x)\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow0}0$, following Daniel Fischer's suggestion (integration  by parts using $(1-\cos x)'=\sin x$) gives

$$
\int^M_0x^{-a-1}\sin x\,dx = M^{-a-1}(1-\cos M) + (a+1)\int^M_0x^{-a-2}(1-\cos x)\,dx
 $$

Putting things together and letting $M\rightarrow \infty$ gives

$$
\int^M_0x^{-a}\cos x\,dx = a(a+1)\int^\infty_0\frac{1-\cos x}{x^{a+2}}\,dx
$$

The integral to the right, as a function of $a$, can be handled by dominated convergence arguments since $0\leq 1-\cos x\leq 2$, $\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}$ is bounded in $(0,1]$, and $x^{-1-a}$ converges to $x^2$ in $L_2(1,\infty)$.
Thus $\int^\infty_0 \frac{1-\cos x}{x^{2+a}}\xrightarrow{a\rightarrow0} \int^\infty_0\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\,dx$.

It follows that $\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\int^\infty_0 x^{-a}\cos x\,dx =0$.